# implenenting AMG8xx Infrared Camera Kernel Module and Video4Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, camera, linux-device-driver, i2c, video4linux

I have found, and forked(https://github.com/firebladed/amg88xx-kernel-driver/blob/master/amg88xx.c), a kernel module for the AMG8xx(http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/ADI8000/ADI8000C66.pdf)  it currently outputs to /sys/ as a text array of values which isn't the ideal output

and am looking at what would be necessary to get it to work with video4linux, i have found the documentation on SOC-camera drivers (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/media/v4l-drivers/soc-camera.html), but its not clear what would be required to actually implement this

can anyone provide an outline or direct me towards documentation of how to do this ?

Comment: Driver is in upstream under Video-for-Linux, so what is the question? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/media/i2c/video-i2c.c

Comment: hadn't found that driver in any searches i had done, so question is probably redundant, as that driver appears to work